# Dynamic Date Validation with PopUp

Tags: java, javascript, validation, date

I have a code to validate the date in the form of `MMYY` format.This shows dynamic popup dialog box before submitting the button. For this the code is given below as:

```
<ext:text name="caseDetailForm" property="phaseData.phaseDateExpiration" styleId="_dateExp"
                    style="width:100px" maxlength="4" titleKey="prompt.exp.date" onkeyup="validateCardExpiry(this);" />
```

and the function is:

```
function validateCardExpiry(field) {
    var cardExpRegEx1or2char = /^(0[1-9]?|1[0-2]?)$/;
    var cardExpRegEx3or4char = /^(0[1-9]?|1[0-2])[0-9]?[0-9]?$/;
    var cardExpDate = field.value;
    var msg = '<bean:message key="errors.bad.input.characters.detected"/> - '+cardExpDate;
        + '\n' + "<bean:message key="prompt.exp.date"/>";
    var failed = false;
    for (var x = cardExpDate.length; x >= 0; x--) {
        cardExpDate = cardExpDate.substring(0, x);
        if (cardExpDate.length > 0 && 
            ((cardExpDate.length <= 2 && !cardExpRegEx1or2char.test(cardExpDate)) 
            || (cardExpDate.length > 2 && !cardExpRegEx3or4char.test(cardExpDate)))) {
            failed = true;
        }
        else {
            field.value = cardExpDate;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (failed) {
        alert(msg);
    }
}
```

for `MMYY` validation is working fine with above code. But i need `MM/DD/YYYY` validation. For this how can i validate with popup window in the same scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
function validateDate(s) {
  var bits = s.split('/');
  var d = new Date(bits[2], ++bits[0], bits[1]);
  return d.getFullYear == bits[2] && d.getDate == bits[1];
}
```

but the format mm/dd/yyyy is not used by that many people, most use either dd/mm/yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd.